# iOS Swift AdMob Native Ads - NSInternalInconsistencyException Could not load NIB in bundle NSBundle with name UnifiedNativeAdView

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am learning how to display `AdMob Native Ads` in `iOS` with `Swift` and I am following this tutorial - [https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/advanced](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/advanced.)

Btw. I don't know if it is releveant, but I don't use `StoryBoards`.

When I run the app and try to display the ad I get the following error - `NSInternalInconsistencyException Could not load NIB in bundle NSBundle with name UnifiedNativeAdView`. The following code is the code throws the `error`:

```
  let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UnifiedNativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first
  guard let nativeAdView = nibView as? GADUnifiedNativeAdView else {
    return
  }
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loadNib loads views from xib/storyboard. But in your case you have to do it programatically.

You need to intialise GADUnifiedNativeAdView like

```
let nibView = GADUnifiedNativeAdView(frame: Position)
// Your other code goes here
self.view.addSubview(nibview)
```